# position: relative does what I want, except it doesn't go to the bottom but doing position: absolute doesn't center it?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

```
<div class="bottom_menu">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row bg_grey bg_border_top_bottom_grey pull-center text-center">
           <div class="col-xs-3 menu_icon">
               <a href="/index">Home</a>
           </div>
           <div class="col-xs-3 menu_icon">
               <i class="fa fa-road fa-lg"></i>
               <a href="/missions">Missions</a>
           </div>
           <div class="col-xs-3 menu_icon">
               <a href="/help">Help!</a>
           </div>
           <div class="col-xs-3 menu_icon">
               <a href="/team">Team</a>
           </div>
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

This is my HTML code, I am using BootStrap for this project if it helps... Excuse the messy code there, still trying to configure it.

```
.bottom_menu {
    position: relative;
    background: #232322;
    bottom: 0;
}


.menu_icon { color: #666; padding-top: 4px; padding-bottom: 3px; }
.menu_icon:hover, .menu_icon:focus {
    color: #777;
    background-color: #333;
    border-radius: 7px;
    -o-border-radius: 7px;
    -moz-border-radius: 7px;
}

.menu_icon a {
    color: #777;
}

.menu_icon a:hover, .menu_icon a:focus {
    color: #666;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

So I guess my issue here is that, when I have my CSS property position set to relative on the bottom_menu class then it will stretch the div out like it's suppose to, but it doesn't go to the bottom. But if I change the position from relative to absolute then it goes to the bottom, but doesn't center the actual menu itself.

I've messed with wrappers a little bit and got the same result, I know I'm suppose to use one but I think my stupidity is preventing me from actually succeeding at the moment.

How would I go about fixing this. Appreciate it all you guys! Thanks!

Comment: You need to set left:0; right:0; for  absolute  position

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using position absolute then you have to use left : 0 and right : 0 to stretch it.

```
.bottom_menu {
    position: absolute;
    background: #232322;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    left:0;
}
```

Hope this might help you :)

- Help

Comment: Yep, that fixed my problem entirely.... Thank you so much, I feel like an idiot now but :D I'll have to accept your answer in 7 mins according to this